# "Sittlichkeit" in contradistinction to "Moralität" and "Ethik"

Tags: translation, german-to-english, synonym

Would "Sittlichkeit der Sitte" be aptly and correctly translated as "Morality of Mores", despite it not having the use of "Moralität"?

Comment: If at all, it should be _Moralität_ with an umlaut.

Comment: Done and done. *thumbs up*

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered without giving (significantly) more context.

Comment: @guidot: "Morality" can be translated into German in several ways; dict.cc lists *Moral*, *Sittlichkeit*, *Tugendhaftigkeit*, *Moralität*. Similarly "Morality" has a number of synonyms in English; Wiktionary lists "decency", "rectitude", "righteousness", "uprightness", "virtuousness". There is no direct correspondence between German and English, so which word is translated to which depends on context. So yes, you can't tell if a translation is "apt and correct" from a short phrase. A full sentence is a minimum; sometimes more than that is needed. One can say it's *a possible* translation.

Comment: @RDBury: Please do NOT post answers in comments. Post answers ONLY as proper answers. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: I don't consider it an answer but a more detailed explanation of guidot's comment that more context is needed. Beginners tend to not appreciate why context is so important in a question like this.

Comment: This doesn't require comment, and is not a intentional question/answer... but why are mods/senior members such "policers" of the forum's rules?  Clearly whether I get the answer in the comments or answer section makes little difference to me.  Especially since I have limited access to the forum, anyhow?  RDBury helped:  That's what I wanted was help.

Comment: I'm not gonna edit my question when a helpful member of the forum gave the context before I did.  Clearly he has some on-hand knowledge that I didn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other mentioned in the comments to the question, without further context it's hard to give a comprehensive answer. But there's one aspect that *probably* is at play here:

In English, there are (at least) two different ways to unterstand "morality". One includes somewhat of a shift in meaning compared to "mores", the other doesn't. In German, "Sittlichkeit" only covers the latter of these variations.

"More", as well as "Sitte", refers to the ways and customs of a community at a certain time. There's little to no judgment. It's more "this is the way we happen to do things", less "this is the way things should be done according to some objective, overarching principles".

"Morality", on the one hand, can refer to those objective, overarching principles - the "this is how things should be done" part. This is the shift in meaning I refered to above. On the other hand, "morality" can refer to something like the aggregate of all mores at a given place and/or time. If, in this meaning, something goes "against the morality", it isn't compatible to the current mores - with no real implication about right or wrong, good or evil.

"Sittlichkeit" covers the latter aspect, but not really the former. If something is "unsittlich", it isn't compatible to the "Sitten" of the place and/or time. It isn't considered decent, it might well get people's knickers in a twist. So, a fitting translation for "Sittlichkeit" would probably be more "decency" than "morality".

Now regarding a translation for "morality of mores", if the first meaning of "morality" is intendend, then "Sittlichkeit" won't cover it. So if we're talking about "are the ways we do things morally justifiable?", then the translation doesn't fit. Here, something like "die Moralität der Sitten" might be a better approach.

If the second meaning of "morality" is intended, then "Sittlichkeit der Sitten" would be a fitting translation. But in this case, the whole phrase seems quite redundant to me.

Comment: Between you and the above comments, this was the kind of answer I was looking for.